# Convert PHP date into javascript date format

Tags: javascript, php, json, datetime, date-conversion

I have a PHP script that outputs an array of data.  This is then transformed into `JSON` using the `json_encode()` function.

**My issue is I have a date within my array and it's not in the correct JavaScript format.  How can I convert this within PHP so it is?**

```
$newticket['ThreadID'] =  $addticket;
$newticket['Subject'] =  $subject;
//$newticket['DateCreated'] =  date('d-m-Y G:H');
```

Instead of the above for the date I need the equivalent of the JavaScript function

> new Date()

When I output the above I get the following "Fri Jun 01 2012 11:08:48 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)" However, If I format my PHP date to be the same, then JavaScript rejects it.  Confused...

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You should probably just use a timestamp

```
$newticket['DateCreated'] = strtotime('now');
```

Then convert it to a Javascript date

```
// make sure to convert from unix timestamp
var now = new Date(dateFromPHP * 1000);
```

Comment: the javascript date format is:  Fri Jun 01 2012 11:08:48 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time) not a timestamp

Comment: No, there are multiple ways of instantiating a date object, including a timestamp: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: @LeeTee The easiest and most transportable format is a timestamp, which you can then convert to whatever you want.

Answer (score 18):

Javascript Date class supports ISO 8601 date format so I would recommend:

```
<?php 
      date('c', $yourDateTime); 
      // or for objects
      $dateTimeObject->format('c');
?>
```

documentation says that:
format character 'c' is ISO 8601 date (added in PHP 5)
example: 2004-02-12T15:19:21+00:00

for more information:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: This works very well with Javascript `new Date();` good answer!

Comment: Ecmascript does not support full ISO 8601. only a simplified version of it

Answer (score 8):

It is pretty simple.

PHP code:

```
$formatted_date = $newticket['DateCreated'] =  date('Y/m/d H:i:s');
```

Javascript code:

```
var javascript_date = new Date("<?php echo $formatted_date; ?>");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be more precise with your timestamp, you should use microtime() instead of now().

That gives you:

```
echo round(microtime(TRUE)*1000);
```

For a milisecond, javascript-like timestamp in php.

Answer (score 1):

Is very simple, I'm use this:

```
new Date("<?= date('Y/m/d H:i:s'); ?>");
```

Comment: @RichardSocker `<?=` is short for `<?php echo ...`

Comment: Thanks man, new thing to me, actually I tried it but I got 500 error maybe cause another error. :)

Answer (score 1):

An improvement or simplification of @jeremyharris answer would be this one:

DateTime objects in PHP have the `getTimestamp()` format, use it and multiply the value by 1000:

```
<?php 
    $phpDateTimeStamp = new Date('Y/m/d H:i:s')->getTimestamp() * 1000; 
?>

// JavaScript
let phpDateTimeStamp = 'YOUR_PHP_VARIABLE';
let startTime = new Date(parseInt(phpDateTimeStamp));
```

Comment: // in JavaScript we have to cast the php timestamp to int 
`let startTime = new Date(parseInt(phpDateTimeStamp));`

Comment: `phpDateTimeStamp` is not defined.

Comment: @mickmackusa in JS code, phpDateTimeStamp should be a variable coming from a $phpDateTimeStamp PHP variable.

Comment: Your code is not implementing this.  This makes your answer misleading/confusing for readers.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this code inspire you I just created that I need.

```
const convertDate = (
    time,
    format = "h:i" // Y-m-d H:i:s 
) => {
    /**
     * Asume the date is 2023-09-01 23:11:01 
     * F = September ; Month as text 
     * M  = Sep ; Month with 3 chars 
     * m  = 08 ; Month with 3 chars 
     * j = 1   : day without zero 
     * d = 01   : day with zero 
     * D = Fri  : day with 3 chars
     * l = Friday  : day with text
     * Y = 2023 : Year Full
     * y = 23  : Year short
     * H = 23  : time for 24 hours 
     * h = 11  : time for 12 hours 
     * i = 11  : minute  
     * s = 01  : Second 
     * 
     */
    if (!time) time = new Date();
    const months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
    const days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];
    const dt = new Date(time);
    const F = months[dt.getMonth()];
    const M = months[dt.getMonth()].substr(-2);
    const m = `0${dt.getMonth()}`.substr(-2);
    const j = dt.getDay();
    const d = `0${dt.getDay()}`.substr(-2);
    const D = days[dt.getDay()].substr(-2);
    const l = days[dt.getDay()];
    const Y = dt.getFullYear();
    const y = `${dt.getHours()}`.substr(-2);
    const H = `0${dt.getHours()}`.substr(-2);
    const h = `0${(dt.getHours() > 12) ? dt.getHours() - 12 : dt.getHours()}`.substr(-2);
    const i = `0${dt.getMinutes()}`.substr(-2);
    const s = `0${dt.getSeconds()}`.substr(-2);
    const vars = ['F', 'M', 'j', 'd', 'D', 'l', 'Y', 'y', 'H', 'h', 'i', 's']
    const formats = vars.forEach(e => {
        format = format.replace(eval('/' + e + '/gi'), (x) => {
            return (eval(x));
        })
        return format;
    })
    return format;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$newticket['DateCreated'] = date('d-m-Y G:H', strtotime($phpDateVariable));
```

Comment: the $phpDateVariable is already in the format you state above.  I need to put into javascript format which is Fri Jun 01 2012 11:08:48 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)

Comment: Are you just asking for how to format a date in PHP? Go look at the formatting options in the documentation: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

The most robust way is to extend your date object to parse strings as objects that your application can use.  A quick example of parsing the mysql datetime string

```
DateFromString(str){
 let months = ["January", "Febuary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
 let date = str.split(" ")[0];
 let time = str.split(" ")[1];

 let [Y, M, d] = [date.split("-")[0], date.split("-")[1], date.split("-")[2]];
 let [H, m, s] = [time.split(":")[0], time.split(":")[1], time.split(":")[2]];

 return {
  FullYear: Y,
  Month: M - 1,
  MonthString: months[M - 1],
  Date: d,
  Time: {Hour: H, Minute: m, Second: s},
 };
}
```

If you are inclined you may include a second parameter that describes the type of string being passed with a default value, and do a string test to determine if it is a unix timestamp or a javascript timestamp or a string, and then use the returned object to parse your date and times, this is a more rounded solution because it will allow you to build an interface that dynamically handles multiple date specifiers.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var phpTimeStamp = '2022-03-20 12:20:20'; /* timestamp format*/

 var jsDateObject = new Date(Date.parse( phpTimeStamp ));
```

Now you can access all property of a date object like

```
 jsDateObject.getHours(); //  gives hour
```

And other functions as well.