# PHP Datetime Object to Javascript Datetime Object

Tags: javascript, php, datetime

How do I convert PHP *DateTime* object to Javascript *Date* object ?

`new Date('06/18/2016')` in Javascript = `Date {Sat Jun 18 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (SE Asia Standard Time)}`

It's easy to get month, just `mydate.getMonth()` but it didn't work when I try to convert date from PHP

`new DateTime('06/18/2016')` in PHP = `Object { date="2016-06-18 00:00:00",  timezone_type=3,  timezone="Asia/Kuala_Lumpur"}` using `mydate.getMonth()` didn't work.

Comment: If you mean [this object](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), it has [`getTimestamp`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php) method returning a timestamp which can be easily converted to JS timestamp by appending 3 zeroes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert PHP date into javascript date format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10837022/convert-php-date-into-javascript-date-format)