# How can I sum a time with a time string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, mysql, date, datetime

i would like to sum this time `15-00-00` with this which is a string: `4 minutes`
I don't know how to convert the `4 minutes` into a correct format and the `15-00-00` into `15:00:00`

here's my code :

```
var reservationDate = '<?= $selectDateReservation[0] ?>';
var reservationTime = '<?= $selectTimeReservation[0] ?>';
var getDuration = '<?= $selectDuration[0] ?>' // returns: "4 minutes"
console.log(reservationDate); // returns the date: 19-05-17
console.log(reservationTime); // returns the time: 15-00-00
```

Comment: Where do those `selectDateReservation`/... variables come from?

Comment: Please remove the php code and replace them by approiate values.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
var date = new Date();
var minutes = 4

date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + minutes);
console.log(date) // Should return your time with the minutes added to it
```

You could convert the minutes with the `getMinutes()` method.

Comment: For the conversion, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10837022/convert-php-date-into-javascript-date-format) will help you.

That way you can actually use the `getMinutes()` method