# Changing date format from numbers to letters

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to change this date format :

```
$date= date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

in to this :

```
Jan 5, 2100 23:50:00
```

to use it here :

```
var acountDownDate = new Date("<?php echo $date?>").getTime();
```

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate. Check link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10837022/convert-php-date-into-javascript-date-format

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert PHP date into javascript date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10837022/convert-php-date-into-javascript-date-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to change this date format...in to this...`Jan 5, 2100 23:50:00`...to use it here...

Don't do that. That string is not in any format that JavaScript's `Date` object is supposed to parse.

Instead, use `c` which provides an ISO-8601 string, which the `Date` constructor supports.

```
$date= date('c')
```

Alternately, since what you want is the milliseconds Epoch value (number of milliseconds since midnight January 1st, 1970 GMT) (I can tell because you're using `getTime()` on the JavaScript `Date`), just output that directly rather than using `Date`. If the milliseconds part isn't really important, use [`time`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) and multiply by 1000:

```
$date = time() * 1000
```

Then:

```
var acountDownDate = <?php echo $date?>;
```

If you want millisecond precision,

Answer (score 1):

Simply do format like this,

```
<?php
$end = date('F j, Y H:i:s');
echo $end;
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/GSBZY

Comment: Except it won't work for what they've said they want.